# How to make the new section go immediately below the previous one?

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this page: http://codepen.io/abdulahhamzic/pen/WwgXRW

Here's the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
<section id="info">
  <p class="info">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    My name is Abdulah Hamzic. I am a beginner front-end web developer with not a lot of experience, but passionate about web-development and ready to learn new things everyday. I have completed the <a href="https://www.coursera.org/account/accomplishments/certificate/A5QYJS26WJ4E" target="_blank"><i>HTML, CSS and JavaScript</i></a> course by the Hong Kong University of Science and Technology and I'm currently doing the University of Michigan <a href="https://www.coursera.org/specializations/web-design" target="_blank"><i>Web Design for Everybody</i></a> specialization, plus the <a href="http://freecodecamp.com/" target="_blank">Free Code Camp</a> path. I haven't built many projects, but you can check some of my first pens here on CodePen below.
  </p>
  <img id="myself" src="https://scontent-fra3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/10453774_522901187836495_1728850695_n.jpg"/>
</section>
<section id="portfolio">
  <h3>This is my portfolio:
  </h3>
  <img src="">
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to make the second section (#portfolio) go immediately below the previous section (#info) and not at the top of the page where the nav bar is? Anyone please help!

Comment: Sure...don't use `position:absolute`..simple.

Comment: I didn't use position:absolute though

Comment: Sure you did...on the #info div.

Comment: http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dMqJwB

Comment: Ayo, thanks homie, I appreciate it :) So, basically, if an element is positioned absolute, other elements that come after it will be placed on the same place as it?

Comment: Essentially, yes, `position:absolute` takes the element out of the flow so it's treated by the other elements as though it wasn't there,

Comment: Thanks once again :) I think I finally understood how things work with positioning and I don't know why the hell I had added position:absolute there in the first place, lol

Answer (score 0):

Just dont use `position:absolute` like Paulie_D says.

Here is the codepen with it working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpxaOg

Comment: Thanks to you too :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, although `position:absolute` is part of the issue, Bootstrap which you have linked in is adding margins to the headings

I would suggest that you either use the Bootstrap layout methods and classes or override the heading margins

```
.h1, .h2, .h3, h1, h2, h3 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

I'd suggest the former.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dMqJwB)